# RegEx to find credit card pattern did not exclude the ones that has more than 16 digits

Tags: c#, .net, regex

We are building a pattern matcher to find credit card pattern (not necessarily a valid one) from a string. Currently we are using this regex from [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html)

```
\b(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b
```

The regex works fine for unless it's trying to exclude invalid numbers that are longer than 16 digits and has space or dash delimiter such as:

> 1234 5678 9001 0000 1111
>   1234-5678-9001-0000-1111
>   1234 5678 9001 00001 111
>   1234-5678-9001-00001-111

The RegEx will include some parts of the numbers and marked them as matched. Which is not what we expected. You can see it live at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8xgT1M/3)

Can anyone help us?

Comment: Visa may [soon be issuing 19 digit PANs](https://www.nccgroup.trust/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2016/november/prepare-for-19-digit-credit-cards/) so the upper limit seems a bit short-sighted.

Comment: Do you intend to capture multiple number by line ? if yes do yo have a separator like the comma in your regex101 sample ?

Comment: @Jimbot yes we intend to capture multiple number in a line but as far as I'm aware of, we haven't designated any specific separator for that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to skip something and only get something else, it is easier to match what you want to skip and match and *capture* what you need to keep.

Use

```
\b(?:(?:\d[ -]*?){17,}|((?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}))\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K4RiPo/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:` - outer non-capturing group:

  - `(?:\d[ -]*?){17,}`  - 17 or more digits optionally separated with 0+ spaces or `-`
  - `|` - or
  - `((?:\d[ -]*?){13,16})` - **Group 1** matching 13 to 16 occurrences of a digit followed with 0+ spaces or/and hyphens
- `)` - end of the outer group to match the strings within word boundaries only
- `\b` - a word boundary

C# code:

```
var values_we_need = Regex.Match(our_text, @"\b(?:(?:\d[ -]*?){17,}|((?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}))\b")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that your have a separator you can split the entry then test it over this regex `^(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}$`:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    var myInput = "5000123456789001, 5000-1234-5678-9001, 5000 1234 5678 9001, 50001234567890010000, 5000-1234-5678-9001-0000, 5000 1234 5678 9001 0000, 5000-1234-5678-90010-000, 5000 1234 5678 90010 000";

    foreach (var cardNumber in SeparateInput(myInput, ','))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"'{cardNumber}' is {(IsThisNumberValid(cardNumber) ? "valid" : "not valid" )}");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static bool IsThisNumberValid(string input)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}$");
}

private static IEnumerable<string> SeparateInput(string input, char separator)
{
    foreach (var splitted in input.Split(new []{separator}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        yield return splitted.Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the separator in the example only to show that I'd like to get multiple numbers in a single line. As for now we haven't designated a specific separator between the numbers